# How do I implement grouped categories plugin using text and images as x axis categories? In highchart?

Tags: highcharts, categories

Something like this? This one uses text + image as one xaxis category. My goal is to have the image as one x axis category and the text label as another category  just like grouped categories except that the example only shows text labels As categories.

```
       $(function () {

        var categoryImgs = {
            'AIA': '<img src="http://dummyimage.com/60x60/ff6600/ffffff"><img>&nbsp;',
            'AMP':'<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"><img>&nbsp;',
            'AMP RPP':'<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"><img>&nbsp;',
            'Asteron Life':'<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"><img>&nbsp;',
            'Fidelity Life':'<img src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"><img>&nbsp;'
        };

        var totals = new Array();
        var stackTotals = new Array();
        var i = 5, j = 0;
        //totals = HighchartsAdapter
        function reverse() {
            totals.reverse();
        }

        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Premium Summary'
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: ''
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {                            
                        return '$' + this.value;
                    }
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray',                                                        
                    },                                                
                    formatter: function () {
                        totals[i++] = this.total;                           
                        return '';
                    }, 

                }                    
            },  

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['AIA', 'AMP', 'AMP RPP', 'Asteron Life', 'Fidelity Life'],
                labels: {
                    x: 5,
                    useHTML: true,

                    formatter: function () {                           

                        var n = totals.shift();
                        return '<div class="stacktotal">$' + n +  '</div><div id="div1" class="myToolTip' + this.value +'" title="Hello ' + this.value + '">' + categoryImgs[this.value] + '</div>';

                    },
                    events: {
                        mouseover: function () {
                            var elm = this.children.div1.className;

                            switch (elm) {
                                case "myToolTipAIA":
                                    $('#hoverboard').html('<img name="testimg" src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"><p>AIA</p>');
                                    break;
                                case "myToolTipAMP":
                                    $('#hoverboard').html('AMP');
                                    break;
                                case "myToolTipAMP RPP":
                                    $('#hoverboard').html('<img name="testimg" src="http://highcharts.com/demo/gfx/sun.png"><p>AMP RPP </p>');
                                    break;
                                case "myToolTipFidelity Life":
                                    $('#hoverboard').html('Fidelity Life');
                                    break;
                                case "myToolTipAsteron Life":
                                    $('#hoverboard').html('Asteron Life');
                                    break;
                            }                                
                        },
                        mouseout: function () {
                            $('#hoverboard').html('');
                        }                            
                    },
                }                    
            },

            linkedTo: 0,
            categories: ['AIA', 'AMP', 'AMP RPP', 'Asteron Life', 'Fidelity Life'],

            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -70,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 20,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                        this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                        'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                        },
                        format: '${y}'
                    }
                }

            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Policy Fee',
                y:'$' + this.value,
                data: [200.12, 290, 45.78, 71, 120]                    
            }, {
                name: 'WOP',
                data: [150, 210.23, 150, 200, 100]
            }, {
                name: 'Income Protection',
                data: [89, 400, 258.13, 212, 152]
            }, {
                name: 'Life Cover',
                data: [150, 210.23, 150, 200, 100]
            } ]

        });           

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like right now formatter for labels in grouped categories plugin is not supported.

You can achieve that by editing sources: http://jsfiddle.net/cFu8z/75/

Just comment out lines `#376` & `#377`:

- https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/blob/master/grouped-categories.js#L376
- https://github.com/blacklabel/grouped_categories/blob/master/grouped-categories.js#L377

Comment: It's working, accepting text and image as categories, but the categories are dynamic data, therefore I need to work with arrays and without formatter function, I would assume it's not possible to do? Is there a way to add categories using array objects or for loop? Thanks! Appreciate the prompt response! :)

Comment: something like this maybe?

Comment: xAxis: {
                    formatter: function()
                    {
                        var i=0;
                        for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                            categories: [{
                                name: xCategories[i],
                                categories: [xCategories[i].logo1,xCategories[i].logo2],
                            }]
                        }
                    },
                    
                    labels: {                        
                        x: xCategories.length,

Comment: I'm not sure what is wrong with actual object of categories? You can use simple categories as numbers (set `categories: []`) and then formatter doesn't have to change: http://jsfiddle.net/cFu8z/76/ . Or even better - why your categories can't be already formatted strings?